# Google cross-platform auth issue

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I create a client ID for web application and another for iOS application in Google API console. We need to get the token from either of this platform with the offline access.

However, to access the data offline, I found that the refresh token obtained by web application client ID can not be refreshed by the iOS client ID. It doesn't work on the other way. How can I create an unique token from different platform so that it can be refreshed with one client ID?

There is a document in Google about cross client auth, but I cannot figure out the way to solve this issue
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth